# JBoss log backup for last 10days

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j

Requirement : We are using JBoss-5.1.0.GA Application server to host our application.I would like to rotate my log on daily basis and to keep the history of last 10 days log files.

Current Situation: At present logs are rolling on daily basis but its just keeping the history of last one day file. Instead of one day, I need my logs to save for last days. Below is the xml snippet in Jboss-log4j.xml

```
  <!-- Rollover at the top of each hour
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
  -->

  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] (Thread) Message\n -->
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>

     <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
    -->
  </layout>
```

I realise using it through MaxBackUp Index but its not working when  we use DailyRollingFileAppender. Please help me.

Comment: <!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
   <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="${jboss.server.log.threshold}"/>
      <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

Comment: <!-- Rollover at the top of each hour
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
      -->

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] (Thread) Message\n -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>

         <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
        -->
      </layout>
   </appender>